# Comparing sql varchar in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8, varchar

I have the Database:

(NumbersAndLetter is VARCHAR, utf8_general_ci)

```
ID | NumbersAndLetter | switch
1 | Uf3zb37FvV| 1
2 | F9bFgsb7F| 1
```

I try to change the database entry with PHP through the NumbersAndLetter, but it will not compare

```
$Something = 'Uf3zb37FvV';

$entry = $intoDB->GetRow("INSERT INTO database (switch) VALUES ('2') WHERE NumbersAndLetter=".$Something);
```

It can not compare `$Something` with the `NumbersAndLetter` of the Database, even if it is the same.
How can I get this work to compare $Something with NumbersAndLetter correctly?

Comment: I think you want an `update` not insert. `Update`, updates an existing value in the db. `Insert`, inserts a new value. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: You could try ```REPLACE INTO```

Comment: Also since `$something` is a string it needs to be encapsulated in quotes when it gets to your DB. `WHERE NumbersAndLetter='".$Something ."'"`. A third note, if `$Something` is ever a value contain a quote it will need to be escaped, if it is user input it should never be passed like this. Prepared statements are a cleaner and safer approach.

Comment: Success? questions? issues?

Comment: Thank you, UPDATE is working, I also must encapsulated the $Something to ('".$Something."')

[quote]$entry = $intoDB->Execute("UPDATE database SET switch='2' WHERE NumbersAndLetter in ('".$Something."')");[/quote]

Nice help here

Comment: See also `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if you need an "upsert".